# How to edit permissions of Databricks queries with REST API?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

I am trying to give `CAN_MANAGE` permission to other users for a given set of SQL queries on Azure Databricks.

Browsing [Databricks REST API reference](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/introduction), under the `Databricks SQL > ACL / Permissions` section there are both [Get object ACL](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions/get) and [Set object ACL](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions/set) endpoints available.

I am able to use the [Get object ACL](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions/get) to return the current permissions however, using the [Set object ACL](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions/set) does not work.

After further investigation I find that the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions) state that:

> The SQL Permissions API is similar to the endpoints of the Permissions/Set. However, this exposes only one endpoint, which gets the Access Control List for a given object. **You cannot modify any permissions using this API**.
>
> There are three levels of permission:
>
> `CAN_VIEW`: Allows read-only access
>
> `CAN_RUN`: Allows read access and run access (superset of `CAN_VIEW`)
>
> `CAN_MANAGE`: Allows all actions: read, run, edit, delete, modify permissions (superset of `CAN_RUN`)

As such, I then moved to try the `Identity and Access Management > Permissions` APIs however [both `Get object permissions` and `Set permissions` rely](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/permissions/get) upon passing a `request_object_type` value.

Looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions) it seems that queries aren't supported:

> The Permissions API lets you manage permissions for:
>
> - Clusters
> - Cluster policies
> - Delta Live Tables
> - pipelines
> - Directories
> - Jobs
> - MLflow experiments
> - MLflow registered models
> - Notebooks
> - Pools
> - Repos
> - Databricks SQL warehouses
> - Tokens

**Payload:**

```
request_object_id = <QUERY_ID>
request_object_type = "sql/queries" # Tested these values also: "queries", "sql_query_id", "query"
generic_permissions_url = f"https://<DATABRICKS_HOST>/api/2.0/permissions/{request_object_type}/{request_object_id}"

generic_permissions_url_response_get = requests.get(generic_permissions_url, headers=HEADERS)

if generic_permissions_url_response_get.status_code == 200:
    print('Data retrieved succesfully.')
    generic_permissions_url_get_parsed = json.loads(generic_permissions_url_response_get.text)
else:
    print('Error retrieving data: ', generic_permissions_url_response_get.text)
```

**Response:**

```
Error retrieving data:  {"error_code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Invalid Object Type"}
```

As such:

1. Is it currently possible to alter query permissions programmatically in (Azure) Databricks?
2. If so, how?

Comment: you can look into the terraform code as a reference: https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/permissions/resource_permissions.go

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks for the link!

However, it is still not clear to me for the [Get object permissions](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/permissions/get) endpoint what `request_object_type` I should be passing for an SQL query...

Trying with `queries`, `sql_query_id`, `query`, `sql/queries` _(from [this line](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/permissions/resource_permissions.go#L308))_ I receive a `{"error_code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Invalid Object Type"}` response.

Are you able to confirm what should be the correct value?

Comment: can you update your question with the payload that you use & command that is used to send that payload

Comment: @AlexOtt Done, eagerly awaiting your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [corresponding documentation section](https://docs.databricks.com/api-explorer/workspace/dbsqlpermissions/get), then you will see that you need to use another URL: `/api/2.0/preview/sql/permissions/{objectType}/{objectId}` instead of `/api/2.0/permissions/{objectType}/{objectId}`. Also, `objectType` should be `queries`, not the `sql/queries`.  Here is a working command for getting queries using curl:

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' 
  "$DATABRICKS_HOST/api/2.0/preview/sql/permissions/queries/$QUERY_ID"
```

gives:

```json
{
  "object_id": "queries/<....>",
  "object_type": "query",
  "access_control_list": [
    {
      "user_name": "....@domain.com",
      "permission_level": "CAN_MANAGE"
    },
    {
      "group_name": "users",
      "permission_level": "CAN_VIEW"
    },
    {
      "group_name": "admins",
      "permission_level": "CAN_MANAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```